Passport JS + React application internal 500 errro
I am creating a general chat application with react, and am stuck while trying to authenticate a user. The axios post request raises a 500 error that I cannot track anywhere. When I put in correct authentication for a user, it says that the password was correct (aka, the user and password was found in the database), but then I believe the serialization/deserialization of the user is messing up somewhere but again, I can't figure it out.
I've tried debugging and logging, it fetches the user properly, un-hashes the password correctly. heres a link to a github repo,
https://github.com/Macpickle/Chatroom-REACT
any help is appreciated, i feel it is something small but again stumping me. thanks.

does the 500 error come with a response, including message and data - a quick browse through your code suggests it should

the error is being raised from my custom errorHandler, where it sends a status and message. though when i log it in the handler, it says "Error: Login sessions require session support. Did you forget to use express-session middleware?", even though it is there.

I certainly can't say but in your code
//initialize passport
 initpassport(
    passport,
    async username => await User.findOne({ username: username }),
    async id => await User.findOne({ _id: id })
 );

 app.use(passport.initialize());
 app.use(passport.session());

this is what you are using, i want you to write those app.use() part above initpassport like this :
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//initialize passport
initpassport(
    passport,
    async username => await User.findOne({ username: username }),
    async id => await User.findOne({ _id: id })
);

Try that and let me know if it works or not!
We'll try some other things after that.

nah unfortunately didn't work, still whenever a user tries to log in, it presents the issue, though with other help of another person i figured out a part of the issue in the errorHandler.js file saying "Error: Login sessions require session support. Did you forget to use express-session middleware?" if that can help you diagnose the specific issue

fixed the issue on my own, figured out to move the external router below the passport initialization as it is required in the router to authenticate a user.
i appreciate your guy's help very much. thank you.
